# Windows Builer - Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, windows10

Alguien sabe porque me salen estos campos vacios cuando quiero usar un JPane en Eclipse. Gracias 
mi sistema operativo es Windows 10.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: seria bueno que especifiques como tienes creado tu proyecto,describe mas sobre los archivos que tienes en el explorador de paquetes, aunque probablemente estas intentando crear el jpane en ningun proyecto abierto. o sea no has seleccionado en el eclipse el proyecto donde vas a crear algun utilitario de java.swing como el jpanel

Comment: tambien es importate que señales que version del eclipse tienes, hay mucha variedad , eclipse mars,oxygen,neon,etc. ya que no todos tienen windows builder para trabajar con formularios y necesitarias hacer un update al eclipse.

Comment: Muchas gracias, era ese el error. Gracias